# Rearranging PHP page so header is before HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

My header is not redirecting to the correct page because I believe I have HTML elements before it. I am new to PHP and need help rearranging my page so this isn't the case. If I replace the header line with

```
print_r("<script>location.href='changepassword.php?success'</script>");
```

it works perfectly, however I know this is not good practise to use JS. Once have been shown the one, I can so the rest as none of them on my website work! Below is my changepassword.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include ("storescripts/init.php");
protect_page();
include ("includes/overall/head.php");
if (empty($_POST) ===  false){
$required_fields = array('current_password','password','password_again');
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
        break 1;
    }
}
if ($_POST['current_password'] === $member_data['mem_password']) {
    if(trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])){
        $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
    } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect';
}
}?>
<body>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <div id="divBreak"></div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
    <div id="middleContent">
        <?php if (isset($_GET['success']) && isset($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'You have been registered successfully';
        } else {
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
change_password($session_mem_id, $_POST['password']);
header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
echo output_errors($errors);
}?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>Current Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="current_password">
                </li>
                <li>New Password*: <br> <input type="password" name="password">
                </li>
                <li>Repeat New Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="password_again">
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Change">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly: PHP header must be executed before any output. It is an important rule. So you have to manage your redirection before begining to print anything (direct HTML or any echo..) and check if your inclusions print something or not. Secondly: Just after a header, you should stop your script with a die, in order to send only header and not content (this not a rule for all case, just for redirection and thing like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This arrangement ought to work. We just move the change password `if()` above any of your document. Note the `die()` command which tells PHP to stop processing. No need to execute the rest of the script when we've instructed the browser to carry on someplace else.

As Dan points out below, you'll want to make sure your `include()`d files do not contain any output.

```
<?php
include ("storescripts/init.php");
protect_page();
include ("includes/overall/head.php");

if (empty($_POST) ===  false){
    $required_fields = array('current_password','password','password_again');
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) == true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1;
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['current_password'] === $member_data['mem_password']) {
        if(trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])){
            $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6) {
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect';
    }
}

if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    change_password($session_mem_id, $_POST['password']);
    header('Location: changepassword.php?success=1');
    die();
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <div id="divBreak"></div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
    <div id="middleContent">
        <?php if (isset($_GET['success']) && isset($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'You have been registered successfully';
        } else {
if (empty($errors) === false) {
echo output_errors($errors);
}?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>Current Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="current_password">
                </li>
                <li>New Password*: <br> <input type="password" name="password">
                </li>
                <li>Repeat New Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="password_again">
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Change">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work. It redirected to changepassword.php not ?success and the page was blank

Comment: If it redirected at all, then it worked. Something in your `changepassword.php` is causing that page to be blank most likely. I would do `changepassword.php?success=1` and then later in changepassword.php `if ( isset( $_REQUEST['succes'] ) ) { ... do something }`

Comment: It didn't really redirect though, just reloaded the changepassword.php which was blank. Just doesn't reload to changepassword.php?success although the page works if entered manually

Comment: my includes head contained html so I moved it to the bottom of the document and its working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your header needs to go before any output. That includes your includes. `include ("storescripts/init.php");`, `include ("includes/overall/head.php");`,`include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");` any output will stop the header.

Comment: If I do that, how do I call the header function in my html?

Comment: Like Set Sail Media showed you. At the very top of the page. Before anything gets outputted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, maybe useful informations if you dont know this.

To make use `header()` function - you have to execute it before any echo, print_r etc.

Other words - "product of" `header();` function must be first data sent to browser.

Answer (score 0):

#### You could use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

**In PHP, headers must be sent before the content.** So once you output *anything* (includes `echo`, `print`, etc, and anything outside the `<?php  ?>` blocks including *whitespace*), then the headers cannot be modified.

**However:** What you can do is turn on output buffering, which will sent all output into a temporary buffer. That buffer will not be output until you tell it to.

The basic pattern is:

```
ob_start();             //Turn on output buffering at the 
                        //   beginning of your script

echo "Hello world!";    //Here would be your HTML document

if ($redirect)          //This would be your condition for redirection
    header('Location: otherpage.php');
else
   ob_flush();          //At the very end, send the buffer to the browser
```

There are a number of options for ending the buffering. In this case I simply flushed the output by using `ob_flush()`, but you can check out the PHP documentation for various other options.

Comment: So I put this inside my opening <?php code block at the top. And before ?> in my last block? I don't need to put this in every php code block on my page?

Comment: Good question... No, not in every php block! Just call ob_start at the top of your page (you should put `<?php ob_start(); ?>` before before `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Now you can render output or call `header()` anywhere you want, and you just have to make sure you flush your output before the script exits. After your closing `</html>` tag put `<?php ob_flush(); ?>`.