# Rearrange my password recovery file so HTML output is below Header

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am slowly getting to grips with PHP, however struggle with breaking up a my if statements so my header functions work. I have done a few but they didn't involve as many conditions as my password recovery file does. Could somebody show me how I can go about doing this?

```
<?php
include ("storescripts/init.php");
logged_in_redirect();
include ("includes/overall/head.php");?>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
<h1>Recover</h1>
<div id="divBreak"></div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
<div id="middleContent">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true){
        ?>
    <p>Thanks, we've emailed you.</p>
    <?php
        } else {
            $mode_allowed = array('mem_password');
            if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'],  $mode_allowed) === true) {
            if(isset($_POST['mem_email']) === true && empty($_POST['mem_email']) === false) {
                if (email_exists($_POST['mem_email']) === true) {
                    recover($_GET['mode'], $_POST['mem_email']);
                    header('Location: recover.php?success');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Oops, we couldn\'t find that email in the system</p>';
                }
            }
            ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>Please enter your email address:<br> <input type="text"
                name="mem_email">
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Recover"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <?php
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
        }
        ?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
```

The header statements need to be above my includes head.php as this includes HTML output. I have tried the buffering however this didn't work for me! Thank you!

Comment: Instead of echoing your results straight out move all your code to the top after `logged_in_redirect();` is a good place all your echo "";'s change to $err = ""; so you're storing your output in a variable. Then just above your <form> put <?php echo $err;?>  and it'll spit out the result of your error.

Comment: Doesn't work, it just redirects to index.php

Comment: thats because you've got your else at the bottom too that needs to be moved up also

Comment: I moved the else up originally and recovery.php just redirects to index.php straight away

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$msg = "";    
if (!empty($_GET)) //check if form has been submitted
{  
   if(isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true)
   {
      $msg = "Thanks, we've emailed you.";
   } 
   else 
   {
      $mode_allowed = array('mem_password');
      if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'],  $mode_allowed) === true) 
      {
         if(isset($_POST['mem_email']) === true && empty($_POST['mem_email']) === false) 
         {
            if (email_exists($_POST['mem_email']) === true) 
            {
              recover($_GET['mode'], $_POST['mem_email']);
              header('Location: recover.php?success');
              exit();
            } 
            else 
            {
              $msg = "<p>Oops, we couldn\'t find that email in the system</p>";
            }
         }
      } 
      else 
      {
         header('Location: index.php');
         exit();
      }
   }
}

include 'storescripts/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();
include 'includes/overall/head.php';
include 'includes/overall/template_header.php';
 ?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
<h1>Recover</h1>
<div id="divBreak"></div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
<div id="middleContent">
<?php echo $msg; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>Please enter your email address:<br> <input type="text"
            name="mem_email">
        </li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Recover"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
```

Didn't you solve this already here? [Rearranging PHP page so header is before HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147163/rearranging-php-page-so-header-is-before-html)

Comment: Thank you, however it won't let me load recover.php?mode=password as it redirects to index.php, even when logged out?

Comment: Edited my answer and that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: It does the same thing, re-directs it straight back to index.php so must be something to do with the location of that 2nd header location

Comment: What does `logged_in_redirect();` do?

Comment: If the user is logged in, then it redirects to index.php because if your logged in then you shouldn't be recovering a password

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start(); // We start the buffer
include ("storescripts/init.php");
logged_in_redirect();
include ("includes/overall/head.php");?>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
<h1>Recover</h1>
<div id="divBreak"></div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php");?>
<div id="middleContent">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true){
        ?>
    <p>Thanks, we've emailed you.</p>
    <?php
        } else {
            $mode_allowed = array('mem_password');
            if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'],  $mode_allowed) === true) {
            if(isset($_POST['mem_email']) === true && empty($_POST['mem_email']) === false) {
                if (email_exists($_POST['mem_email']) === true) {
                    ob_clean(); // Clean the buffer and make the redirect
                    recover($_GET['mode'], $_POST['mem_email']);
                    header('Location: recover.php?success');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Oops, we couldn\'t find that email in the system</p>';
                }
            }
            ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>Please enter your email address:<br> <input type="text"
                name="mem_email">
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Recover"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <?php
        } else {
            ob_clean();// Clean the buffer and make the redirect
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
        }
        ?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php");?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
```

Comment: This does the same thing, still doesn't load the re-direct pages. Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using MAMP

Answer (score 0):

What you may not be aware of is that php sends a header as soon as the first character is echoed out... That first character can even be white space like a lf or tab or cr. etc.

Once that first header goes out, your other headers that you are planning to send will no longer count... So your mixing of text html and use of tags is probably going to hurt you. as the first bit of white space outside of a php tag will generate a header and your planned headers will no longer count.

I could go further and recommend that you start using a templating system to separate code from content.

Comment: Oops... I may be barking up the wrong tree... By header I thought you were talking about http headers.